# Undefined trying to access a variable of a class written in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make this code works properly:

```js
class Reminder {

  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  remindMe(delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(`Your reminder after ${delay} seconds is: ${this.text}`);
    }, delay * 1000);
  }

}

//shows Reminder {text: "Hello World"}
const example = new Reminder("Hello world"); 

//shows undefined
console.log(example);

// shows "Your reminder after 3 seconds is: undefined"
console.log(example.remindMe(3));
```

I have been without working with classes a lot of time, and I know is `undefined` because the method `remindMe` doesnt have access to the constructor, because it doesnt have a getter. But I have tried to create a getter and it didnt leave me to call it from the method `remindMe`, I tried to do something like this:

```
remindMe(delay) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(`Your reminder after ${delay} seconds is: ${getText()});
  }, delay * 1000);
}
```

Any idea about where is the mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `example` is being logged in your code (as you can see from the snippet). It logs:

   ```
   {
     "text": "Hello world"
   }
   ```
2. `remindMe` doesn't explicitly return anything so defaults to `undefined` (that's the first `undefined` in your output). (Note: since `remindMe` is also a function containing a timeout it still wouldn't work because you're logging immediately, and the function only completes after three seconds. Plus it contains its own `console.log` so there's no need to log the result of calling the function anyway.)
3. `this` won't work as you want it to in that `setTimeout` because the context has changed. Use [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead - they have no `this` of their own and "borrow" `this` from its outer lexical environment.

```js
class Reminder {

  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  remindMe(delay) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Your reminder after ${delay} seconds is: ${this.text}`);
    }, delay * 1000);
  }

}

const example = new Reminder("Hello world"); 
console.log(example);
example.remindMe(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `remindMe` method is `undefined` because it doesn't `return` anything, `this.text` is undefined too, because `this` here refers to `window`, you need to `bind` this with `Reminder` Object.

```js
class Reminder {

  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  remindMe(delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(`Your reminder after ${delay} seconds is: ${this.text}`);
    }.bind(this), delay * 1000);
  }

}

//shows Reminder {text: "Hello World"}
const example = new Reminder("Hello world"); 

//shows undefined
console.log(example);

// shows "Your reminder after 3 seconds is: undefined"
console.log(example.remindMe(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're using a `function` as callback in your interval, redefining the context, therefore the value of `this`.

Use `arrow function` instead:

```js
remindMe(delay) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Your reminder after ${delay} seconds is: ${this.text}`);
    }, delay * 1000);
  }
```

The other `undefined` comes from the fact that you're printing the return value of `remindMe` but it doesn't have any `return` keyword, therefore `undefined` is returned.